# List of labels to binary encoding

Tags: python

I have a list of labels:

```py
>>> labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

And I'm trying to write a function `encode` that returns a dictionary with the corresponding encoding for each label:

```
>>> encode(labels)
{"a": (0,0), "b": (0,1), "c": (1,0), "d": (1,1)}
```

The encoder must work for `n` number of labels. For example for two values the encoding should be:

```py
>>> labels = ["a", "b"]
>>> encode(labels)
{"a": (0,0), "b": (0,1)}
```

In summary, for every label, I want to assign a unique binary value. The order of assignation doesn't matter.

Comment: These are exactly 4 labels?

Comment: This is under-specified. You haven't really explained your encoding scheme.

Comment: Can be `n` labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`math.log2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log2) for an arbitrary number of labels:

```
from itertools import product
from math import ceil, log2

def encode(labels):
    return dict(zip(labels, product(range(2), repeat=ceil(log2(len(labels))))))

encode(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
# {'a': (0, 0, 0), 'b': (0, 0, 1), 'c': (0, 1, 0), 'd': (0, 1, 1), 'e': (1, 0, 0)}
encode(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
# {'a': (0, 0), 'b': (0, 1), 'c': (1, 0), 'd': (1, 1)}
encode(["a", "b"])
# {'a': (0,), 'b': (1,)}
```

Comment: Thanks! That accomplishes the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Funny approach:

```
from math import ceil, log2

labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

dig = ceil(log2(len(labels)))
res = {label: tuple(f"{i:b}".zfill(dig)) for i, label in enumerate(labels)}
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': ('0', '0'), 'b': ('0', '1'), 'c': ('1', '0'), 'd': ('1', '1')}
```

To match the expected output:

```
from math import ceil, log2

labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]


def to_binary_tuple(i, d=2):
    return tuple(map(int, f"{i:b}".zfill(d)))


dig = ceil(log2(len(labels)))
res = {label: to_binary_tuple(i, d=dig) for i, label in enumerate(labels)}
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': (0, 0), 'b': (0, 1), 'c': (1, 0), 'd': (1, 1)}
```